# Along the lines of the concept of the inverted spectrum, can it be that musical pitch perception varies as well in an analogous fashion?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, perception, qualia

Imagine hearing your favorite song from the point of view of a dog. Dogs perceive all sounds as being at a far lower pitch than we do. If you could hear what you sound like to a dog you'd find that you sound like a giant with a very deep and low-pitched voice.

There is a remarkable relationship between colors and notes in a musical scale. In music, doubling the frequency corresponding to a given note transposes the note up by an octave. If you double the frequency corresponding to a given musical pitch enough times you will have a frequency that corresponds to a color. That said, it's not that pitch and color are the same phenomenon at different scales but rather that there is an analogy present.

Take for example the note E_5=659.25Hz. Double this frequency over and over until the frequency is the same as a frequency of light corresponding to the color blue. Then take for example the note A_4=440Hz. Double this frequency over and over until the frequency is the same as a frequency of light corresponding to the color red-orange.

If it is indeed the case that musical pitch perception varies among individuals then there are of course some constraints as to how it might vary:

I assume that the ratios between the frequencies corresponding to musical notes is the same for everyone. That is, you and I would agree on the musical interval between between a note and the note that is a tritone above that note. We'd agree it's a tritone, but that only speaks to the ratio, so even though we're both claiming to hear the same song in A♭ it might be the case that if I were to step into your point of view it would actually sound to me like the song is in some key other than A♭.

As in, I think I'd still be able to jive to a song I like if I hear it from someone else's perspective because the musical intervals between every pair of of the notes in the song would still be the same. The intervals dictating how we perceive harmony would not vary from individual to individual.

If it were not the case that the musical interval between notes is the same for everyone, then we'd definitely know about it by now empirically. Some people would experience music drastically different from others and some people would be way off if you ask them to guess the interval between two notes

If what I call orange-red may very well be what you call blue and so on, can it likewise - analogously - be the case that what I call the musical pitch A_4=440Hz is what you call E_5=659.25Hz?

The lower and upper bounds on what frequencies you the reader can perceive as pitch are on average only going to be slightly different than my lower and upper bounds. While abiding by the constraint that we probably shouldn't be that different in that regard, can it nonetheless be that when I hear a song that you and I both agree is in the key of A Major and I prefer a cover of the song that you and I agree is in E Major where the singer has transposed their part up by seven semitones, there may be someone out there who hears the original song in what I would actually consider E Major?

That is, if I were able to step into your mind and hear a song which we both agree is in A Major, could the version that I'm hearing through your ears - metaphorically - sound like it's actually not at all what I would consider A Major.

It's a well-known phenomenon that as you increase the Hz from zero, the sound of a steady rhythmic pulse (beats evenly spaced in time) becomes the sound of some musical pitch. Likewise, if you speed up a repeating [polyrhythm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyrhythm) what you get eventually after having sped it up enough is actually just the sound of a [chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(music)).

If you take an extreme case, can a sound that one person perceives as a polyrhythm be at the same time perceived instead as a number of simultaneous pitches (a chord) by a different person? That seems like a rather extraordinary thing to think about.

Based on what I can understand it seems to me that the perception of pitch is a neat trick our brain performs when the brain chooses not to perceive a series of beats as individual beats but instead as a collective to which one can assign a so-called "pitch".

An illustrative consideration is what it's like to hear sounds as a dog. Things are appreciably lower pitched for them in their subjective experience of a given sound. You can imagine then that you can create a low-pitched enough song which to dogs would sound like a rhythmic ensemble rather than having a discernible melodic line or pitch at any point.

It's also worth pointing out that dogs experience the passage time at a faster rate than we do, by which I only mean that a minute *feels* much longer to them. That being the case, you can imagine that some very low pitched continuous note to which we humans would typically assign a pitch is heard by dogs instead as a series of evenly spaced beats, albeit a series of evenly spaces beats which all occur very close to one another in time

Consider a scenario in which you are recording audio of a singer singing a note. Now imagine that you use Audacity or some other software to slow down the audio by a great amount. The more you slow the audio down, the more clearly you will be able to hear a series of individual beats in rapid succession rather than one continuous, sustained note.

Comment: there is an earnest and interesting question in this, but idk exactly how to even begin to answer, so...

Comment: Does what I hear as the resolution of a tri-tone sound the opposite to you?

Comment: Probably... (I don't know if much more can be said on the topic)

Comment: The starting premise "Just as it can be the case that what I call red is what you call blue" is false. As children we were *shown* colours and told their name. (Colour blindness apart – the inability to distinguish). As for the discussion on sound, a tuning fork will soon dispel that.

Comment: @WeatherVane I had a feeling someone would object to the notion that if I step into your consciousness and see the world through your eye I might see all colors transposed. I've never heard of a way to argue that we all certainly would see colors the same if we step into a different person's perspective. There's a popular Vsauce video where I believe Michael makes a case in favor of the idea that we cannot be certain that color would be preserved upon entering into another person's point of view. How can I convince myself that if I step into another person's point of view color is preserved?

Comment: I used to think that way. It will be even more obvious once you mix primary colours. If it were the case that one person says "that's purple" and another says "'that's orange" it would be common knowledge. The thing that really differs in peoples' worlds is their understanding of what makes the world 'tick'. We can agree on what a table *is* but not *why*.

Comment: "We step into a different person's perspective" is nonsensical. We can stay the same person and only get access to other person's "data", in which case color switch or lack of it entirely depend on how that access is set up, or we can merge and then "we" is no longer we, so color switch, if any, is irrelevant. Either way, "we" do not "step into" anything. Nonetheless, this contrivance seems to be irresistibly enticing to people, and it is amazing how many pseudo-questions can be dismissed once it is thought through.

Comment: Rather than "what I call red is what you call blue", I suspect you mean "how I see/experience red is how you see blue". It's relatively easy to agree on what this thing called "blue" is, but you can't really know what someone actually sees when they look at something you agree is "blue" (although I'm sure I've heard of some studies showing that certain colours evoke the same emotions in different people, which suggests at least somewhat common experiences, even if those may be influenced by culture too).

Comment: @NotThatGuy and if I can't really know what someone actually sees when they look at something that we agree is "blue" then analogously would it follow that I can't really know what someone actually hears when they hear a note that we agree is an E

Comment: *Pitch* is, I was told, a *quasiscientific* concept, being *both* objective (a specific frequency, Hz) and subjective (perception). Also, just like *light* (to which *inverted spectrum* may apply), *sound* too is at the end of they day a *wave* albeit of a different kind.

Comment: There're some youtube videos which humans are barely to hear claim can calm a barking dog, so apparently dogs' hearing spectrum range is different from most people, which is nothing philosophical in itself, just sound physics and physiology of human or dogs hearing organs with their neural processing mechanism. What's interesting is perhaps from the hint of John Keat's famous lyric of a Greecian Urn, human beings may become able to hear soundless sound which is said to be sweeter than all heard melodies. Btw, have you ever wondered what it would feel like through the point of view of light?...

Comment: @DoubleKnot We already know that different people (especially, but not necessarily, those of different ages) are able to hear different ranges of sounds.

Comment: Does different tastes in music suggest different experiences of sound? Or is the same experience evoked, but some people just like it while others don't?

Comment: @NotThatGuy The question has nothing to do with taste in music. To help understand what the question is talking about, imagine hearing your favorite song from the point of view of a dog. It will be very, very low-pitched and hardly recognizable. It will sound like the singer inhaled a heavy gas that makes their voice extremely deep

Comment: @SimonM Do we know how things sound to dogs at all?  It seems like you're assuming dogs would transpose their hearing range into the same mental sounds as ours, but I dont see how that's justified.  Maybe we sound the same pitch to dogs, but they can hear pitches we cant.

Comment: @JMac they for sure hear pitches we can't, hence dog whistles. The transposing of their hearing range is an idea that's been explored by multiple researchers. Using up-to-date scientific knowledge, there is a Youtuber who made a video in which he simulates what it's like to hear the world from a variety of animals' perspectives, including the perspective of a dog. The video is titled "What The World SOUNDS Like To Animals". I try not to make assumptions not based on empirical evidence but perhaps you're right and both I AND the YouTuber are making terrible errors here.

Comment: @SimonM I think it should be obvious that "What The World SOUNDS Like To Animals" is done with the only purpose being to let _humans_ "hear" their sound range.  Obviously to do that, it must be transposed into the human sound range, but it doesnt actually mean the animals themselves hear it like that.  It just would be pretty useless to make a video on "what animals hear" where a bunch of sounds are outside human perception.  It wouldnt sound any different to us, so they need to "translate" to human, it doesnt mean the animals hear it that way.

Comment: @JMac what precisely does it even mean to let humans "hear" their sound range. For instance, if someone were to make a video demonstrating some analogue of what it's like to be a bat in a way that we can make sense of just by watching the video, the thing being simulated is not literally what it's like to be a bat but instead a clever way to analogize what it's like to be a bat. I guess I did make the biggest blunder of all and fail to realize I had the mistaken impression that the video was something you can take literally as opposed to just an analogue suitable for understanding by humans

Comment: @SimonM If what I experience as notes A, B, C, D, E, F, G, you experience as notes G, D, C, E, A, B, F, that certainly seems likely to affect taste in music.

Comment: That's a good point. Maybe a way of testing the idea that people's pitch perception is the same only up to a transposition would be to survey individuals. People who hear music in a far higher key or lower key than average might have a slightly more difficult time enjoying music quite as much as the average because they're hearing songs in a rather extreme pitch range

Answer (score 1):

That question involves a lot of different domains with their own jargon around these things.

Physically it's not just a difference of frequencies between sound and light, but while both are waves, they are different kind of waves.

Sound waves are longitudinal pressure waves. Meaning the oscillation happens in the same direction that the wave is traveling in. So the [wave pattern is a change between compression and decompression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave#/media/File:Onde_compression_impulsion_1d_30_petit.gif).

(this is supposed to be seen as a 2D image, nothing 3 dimensional happening, so the "peak" is just lines being closer together and the "valley" is lines being further apart, so that oscillation (change of peaks and valleys) happens in the same direction in which the wave is traveling).

While light is the usually much more intuitive concept of a transversal wave, meaning the direction in which the wave travels is perpendicular to it's oscillation. So think of standing at the beach and looking at the sea, then the waves come towards you (direction of travel), but the oscillation (the "wave pattern") is up and down, so perpendicular to the direction of motion.

Now I don't know how the biology of this works, but I'd assume that if you were played a sound of  400 THz (light red) on your headphones (might not be as easy to produce as it sounds anyway) you'd likely not feel a light red sensation or really anything because the change in compression/decompression happens so fast that you don't feel it as change at all. so you like won't hear, see or feel that at all.

However as the production of the sound might create a transversal wave pattern on the membrane of the "drum" you might be able to perceive that as colored.

So in order to for your brain to associate a frequency to a color or sound, you'd first need to perceive that and you're likely not going to be able to perceive a steady drum beat or pitch outside of the audible spectrum even if it enters the visible spectrum.

In terms of steady beat and pitch it's much easier. They are both longitudinal waves and a beat, while maybe associated with one event is already somewhat smeared out in time. So if you beat fast enough you're essentially doing the same thing as idk a string or tube of air oscillating. So that's not so much an illusion created by the brain, but the [membrane in your ear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Journey_of_Sound_to_the_Brain.ogv) is actually stimulated with a similar wave pattern. So from the perspective of the ear there is no difference between a fast rhythm and a single pitch. So both perceive that as polyrhythm/pitch.

That said just because you have the same input doesn't mean you have the same perception of that input, so yeah the association of a frequency signal with a sound/color in your brain could be different as it could just be a mapping that happens ever so slightly different for different people.

Now with regards to notes, pitches and intervals things can get even more complicated because that's a mix of physics and perception. Like what note corresponds to what frequency is more or less arbitrary and has changed over time. There are several ways to compute intervals from whole number fractions idk major third would be 5/4 of a tone, to equal temperament where you divide the octave into 12 steps of equal length, then there is a just noticable difference margin around frequencies which is not linear over the whole spectrum but increases with frequency. And then there is an emotional connection to certain sounds. Idk usually the advice to learn to identify intervals is to compare them to the start of common tunes, so if you associate idk a major third with happy birthday that might be more pleasant than a minor third associated with Jaws. On top of there already being a preference for certain intervals because the wave patterns are more similar or different.

So there is a lot of potential to hear different things with the same frequency. From perceiving the note itself differently, to being trained to the octave and thus intuitively correcting a note that is slightly off while people trained to a different scale might perform a different correction. To how these intervals are associated or what intervals are considered in the first place and whatnot. So there are a lot of things coming together and you should probably check physics and music to narrow down your focus.

Comment: It's not about associating a sound to a wave of light with some frequency. It's about associating a pitch to a frequency that is half of half of half of half of half the frequency

Comment: A pitch is the internal representation of a sound wave, so if you half the frequency more and more it becomes too high to be perceptible so there is no sound and conversely no pitch.

Comment: Double the frequency if it's pitch. Halve the frequency if it's light. You got it backwards. Pitch has the lower frequency; light has the higher frequency. You'd be right that if you DOUBLE the frequency of a pitch over and over you would eventually get a dog whistle type noise that you can barely recognize as a pitch and after some amount of doubling you'd no longer be able to perceive a pitch at all because it is above say 20,000 Hz (the upper end of what frequencies a human can typically hear)

Comment: You've confused wavelength and frequency. Shorter wavelengths do correspond to higher pitches and that is what you were getting at. Halving the frequency over and over gives a very low frequency which corresponds to a very low pitched sound. If you halve the frequency of the color blue exactly enough times you will get the frequency corresponding to the note E

Comment: @SimonM Yes I was in a hurry and meant to say double the frequency. Like the A above middle C is 440Hz and the lowest visible frequency is at something like 400THz so about 2³⁰ times more than that. You would leave the audible spectrum in either direction but in the lower end you might perceive it as a steady beat if it is one.

Comment: and as we leave the audible spectrum in the high frequency direction that's when I take a lens in which there is a correspondence that can be drawn - albeit a potentially meaningless correspondence - between colors in the visible light spectrum and musical notes. The weak sort of 'correspondence' is merely the fact that the frequency for blue is a positive integer power of 2 times the frequency for the note E

Comment: @SimonM With all due respect but THAT correspondence is really weak. Like seriously blue has something like 640THz +-30THz and if you also give a margin on error of a few cents for the musical note than with factor of literally something in the order of magnitude of 1,000,000,000,000 you can probably fit any note to any color.

Comment: Given a margin of error you can indeed come up with whatever color-to-pitch associations you want, but in the precise doubling of a frequency there's no margin of error at all to speak of. Take A4=440Hz as an example. Double it enough times and you'll get a frequency that is not approximately but precisely a frequency that falls within a range that humans have mostly agreed corresponds to a precise color. That color will inevitably be a red-orange sort of color. Some people may call it orange but there is no subjectivity or margin of error with regards to the exact frequency.

Comment: @SimonM The problem is that neither the visual nor the auditory frequency can be determined by humans with that level of accuracy. There's something called a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-noticeable_difference which is 3Hz for lower frequencies or ~10 cents for larger ones. And that doesn't yet take into account that there are different tuning systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_intonation or that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concert_pitch changed over the years and the 440Hz is rather arbitrary or that you only see 3 colors red, green and blue and the rest are combinations

Comment: Microtonal and other alternative tuning systems would simply correspond to finer and finer gradations of *theoretical* (not perceived) frequencies. And human pitch perception is irrelevant to the *theoretical* exact frequency of light corresponding to an exact musical pitch's frequency. It's all entirely a theoretical exact science, with no room for error. In practice, yes there are limits to human pitch perception so it is a bit less meaningful to ask individuals what color they assign to a frequency. This still works if we use A_4=432Hz, because the ratios between frequencies is what matters

Comment: @SimonM I thought more about the fact that for example just intonation and equal temperament use either fixed ratios between root and other notes in the interval or use a fixed distance between notes and thus end up with several cents difference between what is expected to be the same note/interval. Though they might coincide for the  octave. Sure you can make the argument in theory, just trying to point out that this integer correlation is likely more of a coincidence given how much wiggle room there actually is on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the relationship between colours and notes in music is not as remarkable as you suggest, being only weakly analogous at best. In our perception of light, there is nothing analogous to an octave, for example, nor is there the sensation of rising and falling pitch we associated with sound, or anything comparable to a chord in which we can still hear the individual tones while also experiencing their combined effect. However, as with light, the sensations we experience are a product of our minds, so it is possible that what you consider to be D is a sound that I consider not to be D, and vice versa. Even where you have two people with absolute pitch, it is still possible that they have different personal experiences of the same pitch.

Comment: Raising the pitch of the note A corresponding to red-orange by seven semitones makes it be transposed over to an E instead. And the color corresponding to E is blue. So in some sense we’ve raised the pitch of a color and the output was a new color

Comment: @SimonM so what? I don't get your point.

Comment: What if you half the frequency of red light- where is the musical analogy there? What if you quadruple it?

Comment: The point is that color and pitch are weakly related in a roundabout way due to the fact that you can double a note’s frequency enough times so that you’ve arrived at an ultra high frequency that corresponds to some unique color

Comment: If you half the frequency of indigo which is at 698 Hz you get the color corresponding to 349 Hz which is a dark red

Comment: Yes, but what if you half the frequency of dark red, or of green?

Comment: My point is that your analogy between music and light is an extremely tenuous one.

Comment: Once you’ve divided some amount of Hz in half you either end up with a frequency that’s on the visible light spectrum or not. I think questions of this form can be answered by finding a table for converting a musical note to its color

Comment: That’s appreciable and I can concede that that is the case

Comment: I do think it is interesting, though, that the spread of visible light is about an octave. I seem to recall a question about that on Physics SE, where the answers explained that it was something to do with electron excitation levels.

Comment: @MarcoOcram It's not inconceivable to have visible octaves. The idea is basically that if you picture a wave pattern with it's ups and downs and then double the frequency, then you'd have all the same ups as before just with more ups in between, so there is some similarities between these two patterns. Compared to other tones where the ups are at very different places. However in terms of the visible spectrum the entire spectrum is slightly less than an octave so you'd need smaller intervals like a major third from light red would be orange and a tritone would be neon green

Comment: i'm not getting the logic here @haxor789 both sound and light are waves so we need to know the frequency to hear anything, unlike with light. makes no sense

Comment: @prof_post Both sound and light are waves and their peaks and valleys can be perceived as a frequency of oscillation, they are different kinds of waves so seeing sound is probably difficult but you could apply the interval between frequencies ideas of pitches to frequencies of light, so as said you can take a major third interval or 1 and 5/4 and have that interval be pleasant or unpleasant with respect to the similarity of the wave function.

Comment: well it sounds like a fun visual/compositional game, but i don't see what it has to do with anything @haxor789

Comment: @prof_post Just wanted to point out that the analogy between light and sound might be better than expected.

Comment: right it's a pretty analogy, but how is it relevant @haxor789 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148826/discussion-between-haxor789-and-prof-post).

Answer (score 0):

> Dogs perceive all sounds as being at a far lower pitch than we do. If
> you could hear what you sound like to a dog you'd find that you sound
> like a giant with a very deep and low-pitched voice.

I can find no evidence to support this claim. Without it, this entire question is based on a false premise and should be closed.

According to this [article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.npsa.gov.uk/resources/introduction-how-dogs-hear%23:%7E:text%3DSound%2520perception%26text%3DTherefore%252C%2520dogs%2520may%2520respond%2520to,frequencies%2520between%2520200%252D15%252C000%2520Hz.&ved=2ahUKEwjBwv3pptGBAxXGJzQIHbmfDUcQFnoECA8QBg&usg=AOvVaw27a3XQerGYx0G2kEpkMF3t) human sensitivity in the lower frequency range is equivalent or slightly better:

- human    64-23,000 Hz
- dog      67-45,000 Hz

According to your logic, a dog who hears a sound at 70Hz, perceives that sound at a much lower frequency than their ears can detect. That makes no sense.

Also, it's not possible to know what a dog perceives.

There is a difference between analog and digital sound. Just like a bitmap has finite resolution (magnify enough and individual square pixels emerge) digital audio has a sample limit. Slow down a digital recording until it reaches the sample limit and you will hear beats since the sample can't be divided any further.

The technique the drummer is using to create a tone is [tremolo](https://Tremolo%20https://g.co/kgs/axKCxb). And classical guitarists use this technique to create the illusion of a single long sustained note: Recuerdos de la Alhambra https://g.co/kgs/9cgjw3 The drummer is trying to get the drum head to resonate at its tuned frequency to produce the tone. This is very similar to the illusion of motion in movies where the frames per second needs to be high enough to give the illusion of motion.

Other percussion instruments using this technique are piano and marimba.

Comment: If I imagine what it would be like to hear a dog whistle from a dog's point of view, I can imagine that I would actually hear the noise instead of being oblivious to it like a human would be. So in order to "simulate" what it's like to be a dog, you must downpitch everything, otherwise the dog whistle would be inaudible to you. Everything in this post is about simulation, I suppose. Then the question can be salvaged if we assume I'm talking about simulation

Comment: @SimonM Your claim is an unsubstantiated opinion. Please provide references to back up your claims.

Comment: The fact is that humans cannot hear a dog whistle because it is too high and I find it silly to provide a citation for that since it's well-known. With simple logic you can conclude that in order to simulate a dog's point of view you must downpitch the world. Otherwise, the dog whistle would be too high to perceive. I used a known fact and then used logic to arrive at the conclusion. It's actually ridiculous to assume otherwise, because then a simulation of dog hearing would no longer be able to show us what it's like to hear a dog whistle

Comment: Also, I do believe that my unsubstantiated claim would not fall under the category of opinion. Just an unsubstantiated claim, about an objective matter, not a subjective matter ripe for opinions

Comment: I think you're implicitly making the claim that the YouTuber who made the video "How The World SOUNDS To Animals" was entirely misguided in his idea for simulating animal consciousness in a way suitable for the purpose of humans watching the video. I'm willing to concede that the idea is misguided only if you concede that the YouTuber was misguided as well. Or, explain why he was not misguided but I am

Comment: Ah, the 70 Hz thing gets into precisely the part where I mentioned "You can imagine then that you can create a low-pitched enough song which to dogs would sound like a rhythmic ensemble rather than having a discernible melodic line or pitch at any point." Pitch becomes rhythm at that very, very low frequency range. The dog can still perceive the 70 Hz sound, but it would sound like a rhythmic beat (albeit very fast) rather than a pitch

Comment: If indeed it's impossible to know what a dog perceives, then that would answer my question in the affirmative. The question is "is it possible that this is the case" and if we cannot know for sure that it's not the case that would mean it is indeed possible. The question was NOT "is this the case", the question was "is it possible that this is the case"